# CCK checkbox or dropdown widget as a field?

Tags: entities, 6

I am trying to setup a new CCK field for a content type to display as a checkbox but I see I don't have that option in the widgets type.
Shouldn't that be included in the default CCK?

I am using the latest CCK for Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox field is provided by the "Options Widget" sub-module included with CCK. From the .info file:

> Defines selection, check box and radio button widgets for text and numeric fields.

If you're not seeing checkbox as an available type you probably don't have that module enabled.